# Release vs Debug version: suddenly runtime error

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime

I have a program that performs an FFT on a 2d array. In order to work with the fft library fftw3 I have to use a temporary array (called FTtemp) that reads out the result of the FFT: it is 3d since it contains the x & y axis plus the real and imaginary value for each (x,y) tupel.

The transfer of the data from the FFT array (which has a special variable type) to the ordinary array is working in debug mode but not in release. In release I get the following runtime error:  Access violation writing location 0x02913000.

From my google search I found that release version bugs are usually related to uninitialized objects. This led me to explicitly initialise every item in FTtemp with 0.0, however to no avail. Furthermore, I printed the FFt array items to console and numbers appeared which means that they are also initialised. Hence, I am a bit out of ideas and wondered if someone might be wiser than me?

Here is the code snippet I am talking about. Since the program relies on a lot of other things, I was not quite able to recreate a minimal example yet, but I will add one as soon as I got the same error.

Fun fact: I print the I & j values of the loop to the console for trouble shooting and it is another (I,j) tupel where it crashes every time when I run it: eg: 49,212 or 116,169. I am really confused by this.

```
        FTtemp = new double** [width];
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            FTtemp[i] = new double*[height];
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                FTtemp[i][j] = new double[2]; 
                FTtemp[i][j][0] = 0.0;
                FTtemp[i][j][1] = 0.0;
            }
        }

        cout << "width,height: " << width << "," << height << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                /*
                cout << "access to out: " << out[indexFFT(i, j)][0] << endl;
                cout << "access to FTtemp: " << FTtemp[i][j][1] << endl;
                */
                cout << "i,j is: " << i << "," << j << endl;
                FTtemp[i][j][1] = out[indexFFT(i, j)][0]; <--------- error occours here
                FTtemp[i][j][2] = out[indexFFT(i, j)][1];
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your consideration. 
All the best,
Blue

Comment: `FTtemp[i][j][2]` is an out of bounds access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in this line:

```
FTtemp[i][j][2] = out[indexFFT(i, j)][1];
```

Notice that `FTtemp[i][j]` is initialized to `new double[2]` earlier in your code, which means that `FTtemp[i][j][2]` is an out-of-bounds write.

There may be other issues here - perhaps `indexFFT(i, j)` gives a bad index? - but without seeing how `out` was initialized or how `indexFFT` works we can't be sure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are quite right. no idea how it was running in debug mode and giving good results o.O let me test that.

Comment: The fun part about C++ coding is that operations like these result in *undefined behavior*, meaning that you can't make many assumptions about what happens. It could coincidentally work without crashing, or it could crash, or it could be fine but break something downstream. You just don't know.

Have you looked into using a tool like `valgrind`? It's great for identifying out-of-bounds reads and writes, along with all sorts of other errors.

Comment: @BlueMoon Because you're using raw pointers and there is no bounds checking on those, even in debug mode.  You probably clobbered the overrun data, which should be detected when freeing the memory.

Comment: I have no idea what clobbed means or how to free memory (sorry, non native speaker and newbie here ^^') but I now understand how this was able to slip past my attention. Thank you all for the quick help and for giving explanation how C++ works so that I can watch out for that in the future!